# jquery.jeditable.ajaxupload.js how to send file?

Tags: jeditable

maybe somebody can to explain me why I can't send file, maybe needed additional script or something els?

```js
/*
 * Ajaxupload for Jeditable
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008-2009 Mika Tuupola
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Depends on Ajax fileupload jQuery plugin by PHPLetter guys:
 *   http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/
 *
 * Project home:
 *   http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable
 *
 * Revision: $Id$
 *
 */
 
$.editable.addInputType('ajaxupload', {
    /* create input element */
    element : function(settings) {
        settings.onblur = 'ignore';
        var input = $('<input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" />');
        $(this).append(input);
        return(input);
    },
    content : function(string, settings, original) {
        /* do nothing */
    },
    plugin : function(settings, original) {
        var form = this;
        form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        $("button:submit", form).bind('click', function() {
            //$(".message").show();
            // Modification to include original id and submitdata in target's querystring
  var queryString;
  if ($.isFunction(settings.submitdata)) {
   queryString = jQuery.param(settings.submitdata.apply(self, [self.revert, settings]));
  } else {
   queryString = jQuery.param(settings.submitdata);
  }
  if (settings.target.indexOf('?') < 0) {
   queryString = '?' + settings.id + '=' + $(original).attr('id') + '&' + queryString;
  } else {
   queryString = '&' + settings.id + '=' + $(original).attr('id') + '&' + queryString;
  }
  settings.target += queryString;
            // End modification
            $.ajaxFileUpload({
                url: settings.target,
                secureuri:false,
                // Add the following line
                data    : settings.submitdata,

                fileElementId: 'upload',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data, status) {
                    $(original).html(data);
                    original.editing = false;
                },
                error: function (data, status, e) {
                    alert(e);
                }
            });
            return(false);
        });
    }
});


$(\".ajaxupload\").editable('/?action=upload_profile_photo', {
 indicator : '<i class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-pulse\"></i>',
 type      : 'ajaxupload',
 submit    : 'Upload',
 cancel    : 'Cancel',
 tooltip   : \"Click to upload...\"
 });
```

```html
<p class=\"ajaxupload\" id=\"profile_photo\"><img class=\"img-thumbnail img-responsive\" src=\"http://www.in-elite.com/?action=no_image_text\" alt=\"\"></p>
```

how result its passed only

> print_r($._GET)Array ( [action] => upload_profile_photo [id] =>
>   profile_photo ) print_r($._POST)Array ( [value] => 20150501_153530.jpg
>   [id] => profile_photo )

And question so, **How to send file?**

Answer (score 0):

Ux I found the problem ;-)

I'm forgot to add one js file called jquery.ajaxfileupload.js

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/includes/JS/jquery.ajaxfileupload.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>
```

And content of this jquery.ajaxfileupload.js file is

```
jQuery.extend({

    createUploadIframe: function(id, uri)
    {
            //create frame
            var frameId = 'jUploadFrame' + id;

            if(window.ActiveXObject) {
                var io = document.createElement('<iframe id="' + frameId + '" name="' + frameId + '" />');
                if(typeof uri== 'boolean'){
                    io.src = 'javascript:false';
                }
                else if(typeof uri== 'string'){
                    io.src = uri;
                }
            }
            else {
                var io = document.createElement('iframe');
                io.id = frameId;
                io.name = frameId;
            }
            io.style.position = 'absolute';
            io.style.top = '-1000px';
            io.style.left = '-1000px';

            document.body.appendChild(io);

            return io           
    },
    createUploadForm: function(id, fileElementId)
    {
        //create form   
        var formId = 'jUploadForm' + id;
        var fileId = 'jUploadFile' + id;
        var form = $('<form  action="" method="POST" name="' + formId + '" id="' + formId + '" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>'); 
        var oldElement = $('#' + fileElementId);
        var newElement = $(oldElement).clone();
        $(oldElement).attr('id', fileId);
        $(oldElement).before(newElement);
        $(oldElement).appendTo(form);
        //set attributes
        $(form).css('position', 'absolute');
        $(form).css('top', '-1200px');
        $(form).css('left', '-1200px');
        $(form).appendTo('body');       
        return form;
    },

    ajaxFileUpload: function(s) {
        // TODO introduce global settings, allowing the client to modify them for all requests, not only timeout        
        s = jQuery.extend({}, jQuery.ajaxSettings, s);
        var id = new Date().getTime()        
        var form = jQuery.createUploadForm(id, s.fileElementId);
        var io = jQuery.createUploadIframe(id, s.secureuri);
        var frameId = 'jUploadFrame' + id;
        var formId = 'jUploadForm' + id;        
        // Watch for a new set of requests
        if ( s.global && ! jQuery.active++ )
        {
            jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxStart" );
        }            
        var requestDone = false;
        // Create the request object
        var xml = {}   
        if ( s.global )
            jQuery.event.trigger("ajaxSend", [xml, s]);
        // Wait for a response to come back
        var uploadCallback = function(isTimeout)
        {           
            var io = document.getElementById(frameId);
            try 
            {               
                if(io.contentWindow)
                {
                     xml.responseText = io.contentWindow.document.body?io.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML:null;
                     xml.responseXML = io.contentWindow.document.XMLDocument?io.contentWindow.document.XMLDocument:io.contentWindow.document;

                }else if(io.contentDocument)
                {
                     xml.responseText = io.contentDocument.document.body?io.contentDocument.document.body.innerHTML:null;
                    xml.responseXML = io.contentDocument.document.XMLDocument?io.contentDocument.document.XMLDocument:io.contentDocument.document;
                }                       
            }catch(e)
            {
                jQuery.handleError(s, xml, null, e);
            }
            if ( xml || isTimeout == "timeout") 
            {               
                requestDone = true;
                var status;
                try {
                    status = isTimeout != "timeout" ? "success" : "error";
                    // Make sure that the request was successful or notmodified
                    if ( status != "error" )
                    {
                        // process the data (runs the xml through httpData regardless of callback)
                        var data = jQuery.uploadHttpData( xml, s.dataType );    
                        // If a local callback was specified, fire it and pass it the data
                        if ( s.success )
                            s.success( data, status );

                        // Fire the global callback
                        if( s.global )
                            jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxSuccess", [xml, s] );
                    } else
                        jQuery.handleError(s, xml, status);
                } catch(e) 
                {
                    status = "error";
                    jQuery.handleError(s, xml, status, e);
                }

                // The request was completed
                if( s.global )
                    jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxComplete", [xml, s] );

                // Handle the global AJAX counter
                if ( s.global && ! --jQuery.active )
                    jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxStop" );

                // Process result
                if ( s.complete )
                    s.complete(xml, status);

                jQuery(io).unbind()

                setTimeout(function()
                                    {   try 
                                        {
                                            $(io).remove();
                                            $(form).remove();   

                                        } catch(e) 
                                        {
                                            jQuery.handleError(s, xml, null, e);
                                        }                                   

                                    }, 100)

                xml = null

            }
        }
        // Timeout checker
        if ( s.timeout > 0 ) 
        {
            setTimeout(function(){
                // Check to see if the request is still happening
                if( !requestDone ) uploadCallback( "timeout" );
            }, s.timeout);
        }
        try 
        {
           // var io = $('#' + frameId);
            var form = $('#' + formId);
            $(form).attr('action', s.url);
            $(form).attr('method', 'POST');
            $(form).attr('target', frameId);
            if(form.encoding)
            {
                form.encoding = 'multipart/form-data';              
            }
            else
            {               
                form.enctype = 'multipart/form-data';
            }           
            $(form).submit();

        } catch(e) 
        {           
            jQuery.handleError(s, xml, null, e);
        }
        if(window.attachEvent){
            document.getElementById(frameId).attachEvent('onload', uploadCallback);
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById(frameId).addEventListener('load', uploadCallback, false);
        }       
        return {abort: function () {}}; 

    },

    uploadHttpData: function( r, type ) {
        var data = !type;
        data = type == "xml" || data ? r.responseXML : r.responseText;
        // If the type is "script", eval it in global context
        if ( type == "script" )
            jQuery.globalEval( data );
        // Get the JavaScript object, if JSON is used.
        if ( type == "json" )
            eval( "data = " + data );
        // evaluate scripts within html
        if ( type == "html" )
            jQuery("<div>").html(data);
            //jQuery("<div>").html(data).evalScripts();
            //alert($('param', data).each(function(){alert($(this).attr('value'));}));
        return data;
    }
})
```

Now everything ok and file are uploaded successfully.... Just needed to modified php script for which type of the data you need to upload